# Is there a way to make all my link books automatically intra linking?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mystcraft

In mystcraft 1.7.2 is there a 100% way to make all books intra-linking? (so they can link and be used in the same world)

Note that changing configs or some server admin only method are acceptable solutions.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I assume that you could get one intra-linking page and stick it in an infinite item source (Factorization has one, but I'm sure there are others). You could probably also figure out the the data values needed and use a command-block to spawn them in.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently assuming that you are attempting to use intra-linking books as a private warp in your server.

This is listed in the configs of the mod.

```
general {
    B:crafting.linkeffects.disarm.enabled=true
    B:crafting.linkeffects.following.enabled=true
    B:crafting.linkeffects.generate_platform.enabled=true
    B:crafting.linkeffects.intra_linking.enabled=true
    B:crafting.linkeffects.maintain_momentum.enabled=true
    B:crafting.linkeffects.relative.enabled=true
```

You could disable all other effects to prevent anything other than intra-linking from showing up. You should still use the correct materials to cause the effect.

Do take note this does not guarantee a intra-linking book but instead prevent other effects from showing up. If you require such a feature i would suggest requesting it at the mystcraft forums linked below

http://binarymage.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=21

---

Additionally an alternate solution to this would be to spawn in a link modifier and place it at the spawn of your server protected from destruction but allow usage using plugins . I am not sure what would happen if some of the effects are disabled, but it would guarantee a intra-linking book.

Comment: You can't disable "no extra effect", so this won't help, the chance for a following book will still be the same.

Comment: @Arperum Have you attempted this? Do take note the actual visual effect is only visible when you do it both server side and client side. If it is only done server side, it will still show as if it will have the chance to give other effect. And also i dont understand what you mean by "no extra effect"

Comment: I have not attempted and am not able to test it any time soon. "No extra effect" is basically the default thing you get from a linking book, just like when you don't add any special material.

Comment: @Arperum If you have down voted this answer, I have revised it to add in information that this is an alternate solution if he cannot find 1. It does not guarantee a intra-linking book but gets it close enough to almost guarantee it.

Comment: It was indeed me, consider yourself redeemed! Thanks for fixing your answer.